What type of Python library or language to use for a scheduling app?
I would like to develop a small app that creates a team schedule for a whole month all year. The generated output could be something like this:

I would like to try it in Python, but advice is welcomed.
I tried to look at tkinter, tkcalendar, Flet, Schedule
